# Extended sequence unpacking in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I create a list as:

```
>>> seq = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now i assign the variables as follows:

```
>>> a, b, c, d, *e = seq
>>> print(a, b, c, d, e)
```

I get output as:

```
>>> 1 2 3 4 []
```

Now i change the sequence in which i assign variables as:

```
>>> a, b, *e, c, d = seq
>>> print(a, b, c, d, e)
```

I get output as:

```
>>> 1, 2, 3, 4, []
```

So my question is Why ***e** variable above is always assigned an empty list regardless of where it appears?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a design choice, according to [PEP 3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) (with my bold):

> A tuple (or list) on the left side of a simple assignment (unpacking is not defined for augmented assignment) may contain at most one expression prepended with a single asterisk (which is henceforth called a "starred" expression, while the other expressions in the list are called "mandatory"). This designates a subexpression that will be assigned a list of all items from the iterable being unpacked **that are not assigned to any of the mandatory expressions**, or an empty list if there are no such items.

Indeed, the first example in the PEP illustrates your point:

```
>>> a, *b, c = range(5)
>>> a
0
>>> c
4
>>> b
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 6):

In the first case

```
a, b, c, d, *e = seq
```

since the sequence has only four elements, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` get all of them and the rest of them will be stored in `e`. As nothing is left in the sequence, `e` is an empty list.

In the second case,

```
a, b, *e, c, d = seq
```

First two elements will be assigned to `a` and `b` respectively. But then we have two elements after the `*e`. So, the last two elements will be assigned to them. Now, there is nothing left in the `seq`. That is why it again gets an empty list.

Answer (score 3):

```
a, b, *e, c, d = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`*e` says "what's left put into `e`". Because you have 4 elements, empty sequence is put into `e`.