# Python read items from a file into a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to read values from a file and get them into a dictionary as lists so I can later use them in functions, for example get the sum of Maths KT and get the length of the list and check if contains atleast 5 values and so on.

The code I have for getting the file into a dictionary.

```
    s = {}
f = open("file.txt")
lines = f.readlines()

for i in lines:
    if not ":" in i:
        if i.strip() == "":
            pass
        else:
            s[i.strip()] = {}
    elif ":" in i:
        x = i.strip().split(":")
        s[next(iter(s))][x[0]] = x[1].split(",")

print(s)
f.close()
```

It currently prints it out like this:

```
 {'Maths': {'TK': [' 1', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 0.5'], 'KT': [' 25', ' 10'], 'Tests': [' 10', ' 7'], 'KD': [' 10', ' 15', ' 25']}, 'Physics': {}}
```

It replaces Maths values with Physics values and just adds unique Physics values to Maths, leaving Physics dictionary empty.

But it needs to look like this so I can use the keys and values:

```
{'Maths': {'TK': [' 1', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 0.5'], 'KT': [' 26', ' 24', ' 20'], 'Tests': [' 2 ', '2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 1'], 'KD': [' 5', ' 1']}, 'Physics': {'KD': [' 10', ' 15', ' 25'], 'KT': [' 25', ' 10'], 'Tests': [' 10', ' 7']}
```

How the file "file.txt" looks like (It will have more lines and values):

```
Maths

TK: 1, 2, 2, 2, 0.5
KT: 26, 24, 20
Tests: 2 ,2, 2, 2, 1
KD: 5, 1

Physics

KD: 10, 15, 25
KT: 25, 10
Tests: 10, 7
```

Comment: Your example file has many blank lines. Does it actually have lines with the text `-Empty line-`?  Are there *headings* other than `Maths` or `Physics`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your file looks like this in actuality:

```
Maths

TK: 1, 2, 2, 2, 0.5
KT: 26, 24, 20
Tests: 2 ,2, 2, 2, 1
KD: 5, 1

Physics

KD: 10, 15, 25
KT: 25, 10
Tests: 10, 7
```

You just need a minor modification to cache your main dictionary key.  I've updated your code to also use a [`with` context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) as well, which you should get into the practice of using:

```
s = {}
key = ''                                    # add a tracer for the main dictionary key
with open("test.txt", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for i in lines:
        if not ":" in i:
            if i.strip() == "":
                pass
            else:
                key = i.strip()             # cache the category as key            
                s[key] = {}                 # create the main key
        else:                               # you just need an else here since the condition are polar opposites.
            x = i.strip().split(":")
            s[key][x[0]] = x[1].split(",")  # use key here instead of next(iter(s))

    print(s)
```

Output:

```
{
  'Maths': 
    {
      'TK':    [' 1', ' 2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 0.5'], 
      'KT':    [' 26', ' 24', ' 20'], 
      'Tests': [' 2 ', '2', ' 2', ' 2', ' 1'], 
      'KD':    [' 5', ' 1']
    },
  'Physics': 
    {
      'KD':    [' 10', ' 15', ' 25'],
      'KT':    [' 25', ' 10'],
      'Tests': [' 10', ' 7']
    }
}
```

The reason why your code didn't work was that `next(iter(s))` creates a new iterator for `s` each time and therefore is not consistent behaviour.

Comment: Once you read all the lines - `lines = f.readlines()`  - you can *exit* the with statement.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over the file; skip blank/empty lines; split each line on `':'`; if there wasn't a colon it must be a new *topic* - create a new dictionary; if there was a colon add to the current dictionary.

```
data = {}
for line in f:
    if len(line) == 1:
        continue
    line = line.strip()
    k,*v = line.split(':')
    if not v:
        d = {}
        data[k] = d
    else:
        d[k] = v[0].split(',')
```

---

Takes advantage of [extended unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956772/extended-sequence-unpacking-in-python3)
Assumes that a *topic* isn't repeated later in the file - there is only one `Maths` section in the file.

Comment: I believe the `-Empty line-` in the example is literally a blank line based on the code given.

Comment: I understand that.  But based on the context I'm leaning toward that being the case.  Regardless, just my comment :)

Comment: Those -Empty line- are just an empty lines in the file. Didn't know how to correctly type it in.